# How does onClickListitem() works in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I have just started learning android programming through Big Nerd Ranch guide. However, I am stuck on this onClickListItem() item method to get the clicks on the correct item. What I don't get is that how are we getting the current position of each item when we are not even specifying the position?
For instance, we have this method

```
public void onClickListItem(ListView l, View v, int position,long id)
{
   Crime c=(Crime) getAdapter().getItem(position);
}
```

Now how exactly we are getting the correct item that I click on my device screen in the log? because we did not specify which position it is. I mean we havent made any call to that method saying the position is 0 or 1 or 2. Moreover, whats the purpose of this long id? 
Please Explain in detail Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how exactly we are getting the correct item that I click on my
>   device screen in the log? because we did not specify which position it
>   is. I mean we havent made any call to that method saying the position
>   is 0 or 1 or 2.

It is the `Adapter` that adapts your dataset - a `Collection` of `Crime` objects in your case - to the View's representation. The representation order is equal to the insertion order of your dataset. The adapter, internally, access the dataset at every position, and draw the information  on the the ListView's row. This happens in `getView`,

> Moreover, whats the purpose of this long id?

it is the row id, of the item you clicked on. It could be, for instance, the primary key field `_ID`, of a row in your database.